# Heading angle for waypoint navigation (fails at bounds)

Tags: algorithm, vector

In a Cartesian coordinate system / Euclidian plane, a vehicle travels clockwise around the origin with radius 1 and currently at angle θ = PI/4 (45°), so its heading is `7/4*PI` (315°).
To reach its new destination (the origin) it should change course (instantly) to `-5/4*PI` (-135°).

This angle can be obtained with e.g. `atan2` on the components of the vector from position to target (with the target at origin, it's the the inverted position vector)b:

- [Finding Signed Angle Between Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150050/finding-signed-angle-between-vectors)
- [Using atan2 to find angle between two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors/)
- [Algorithm Improvement: Calculate signed change in heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238136/algorithm-improvement-calculate-signed-change-in-heading)

However, due to inertia, the vehicle cannot change its course instantly and crosses the X-axis (x=1, y=0, θ=0), where a new calculation results in a course of `PI` (180°).

The vehicle tries to achieve this new (positive angle) course by a positive turn (counterclockwise, CCW), which takes it back across the X-axis, and so on (it "wiggles" away from the target along the x-axis).

It breaks also if negative angles are "wrapped" into the absolute positive range `0...2PI` - example data of the southbound vehicle passing west of the target:

```
course -0.00477
adjust  6.27840

course  0.00034
adjust  0.00034
```

The proportional control then basically causes a negative (clockwise) turn, which is the wrong direction.

Do I eliminate this "overflow" somehow (not limit to `0...2PI` but map absolute angles to the vehicle's) or should I use a different strategy altogether (which)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not limiting the vehicle angle to 0...2PI, i.e. allowing negative and large angles seems to be a promising approach.

E.g. going from 10° to 350°=-10° means a -20° turn.

This determines the heading with the smallest turn angle:

```
delta = course - heading%fullcircle
if (delta >  halfcircle)
  delta = delta - fullcircle
if (delta < -halfcircle)
  delta = delta + fullcircle
newheading = heading + delta
```

`halfcircle` and `fullcircle` correspond to `180°`/`PI` and `360°`/`2*PI` respectively.

The vehicles `heading` will "wind up" if it's going circles, but if need be, this could be restored by an occasional modulo operation.